# Implementing Observer Pattern in Delphi with Interface

Tags: delphi, interface, free, observer-pattern, invalidoperationexception

First of all, Hello for everybody and thanks for your help.

I'm trying to implement the Observer Pattern in Delphi using Interfaces, so an Object could be a Subject and an Observer at the same time.

I have a class that implements ISubject, with the following method:

```
procedure TSomeClass.Attach(const observer: IObserver);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Fobservers = nil then
  begin
    Fobservers := TInterfaceList.Create;
  end;
  if Fobservers.IndexOf(Observer) < 0 then
    Fobservers.Add(Observer);
end;
```

I followed Joanna Carter's example at http://blogs.teamb.com/joannacarter/2004/06/30/690.

In the application, I instantiate an object that implements the IObserver, and attach it to the TSomeClass object (which implements ISubject as well).

Then I call the Notify method from the TSomeClass object and it works correctly. My problem occurs when I try to FreeAndNil my Observer object, because I get an Invalid Pointer Operation, even though I'm using 'const' in the parameter and when I reach the FreeAndNil line in debug mode, the object is properly assigned, with all properties set and with a random property changed inside the notify.

I noted that I couldn't Free my object anymore when I call this line:

```
Fobservers.Add(Observer);
```

If I comment this line, then I can free my object. The code inside the application looks like this:

```
procedure TfrmAlisson.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  locSomeClass: TSomeClass;
  locObserver: TSomeObserverClass;
  I: Integer;
begin
  locObserver:= TSomeObserverClass.create(394693);
  try
    locSomeClass:= TSomeClass.create(263151);
    try
      locSomeClass.Attach(locObserver);
      locSomeClass.NotifyObservers;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(locSomeClass);
    end;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(locObserver.SomeProperty)); // This property is changed inside the notify
  finally
    locObserver.Free; // error
  end;
end;
```

I would like to know why adding the IObserver to the TInterfaceList causes this (I'm using Delphi 2009).

Comment: You appear to be mixing reference counted interfaces with classes. Anyway, we will still have to guess. Supply an SSCCE to take the mystery out of it all.

Comment: See http://sscce.org. if, like me, the "initialism" SSCCE confused you

Comment: @David See any websearch engine if you don't know what something means. This is a basic intelligence test. Can somebody work out what SSCCE is? If not, they are probably beyond redemption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TSomeObserverClass` is most likely inheriting from `TInterfacedObject`.

When you pass it in `Attach` it gets passed as `IObserver` and this is where the reference counting kicks in. The RefCount goes to 1 when it gets added to `Fobservers` and when you destroy `locSomeClass` and with it the `Fobservers` list it gets removed again which causes the RefCount to drop to 0. Then the instance behind the `IObserver` interface reference is being destroyed.

To show the problem here is the minimal code to reproduce it:

```
var
  obj: TInterfacedObject;
  list: TInterfaceList;
begin
  o := TInterfacedObject.Create;
  try
    list := TInterfaceList.Create;
    list.Add(o);
    list.Free;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(o);
  end;
end;
```

If you execute this you see the EInvalidError in the FreeAndNil which is caused because the instance was already destroyed by the automatic reference counting implemented in `TInterfacedObject`.

As already commented you should not mix object and interface references *or* inherit from a class that does not implement automatic reference counting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I saw that in Delphi, people usually use classes to implement this pattern, one class for Observer and other for Subject, but in my situation, I can have an object that is both simultaneously, so I've created a class TObserverSubject that implement both behaviours. The Observer Update method, inside this class, just raise an Exception, because this method is virtual and must be overridden in child classes. I could put this method as abstract as well, but I would have problems.